# "Your account has been disabled" error message

Tags: permission-sets, user-management, trailhead

Recently while completing a Trailhead exercise I noticed when attempting to assign a Permission Set to a user I was receiving this error message.

> "Your account has been disabled". Your company administrator has disabled access to the system for you. Please contact your administrator for more information.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I spend some time digging deep into why I could not assign a Permission Set to multiple users within my DE org (Developer Edition) to come to the realization that these users were inactive within the environment.

I just want to post this as an answered question incase anybody else has this issue.

Comment: Often the problem with DE orgs is the 2 active user limit on the Salesforce and Platform user licences, it makes it a pain having to keep activating and deactivating to do different things.

Comment: It sure is a pain @DaveHumm. Not a huge fix needed for this issue but if somebody is unsure as to why they are seeing this, then thats when they may consume a lot of time thinking its a bigger issue than what it actually is.

Comment: Thanks, this saved my bacon! Such a terrible error message...